# SQL Server Union query pieces work individual but not as union

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a union query that previously worked fine. However if I try to run the query now I get the following error

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I have tried running each individual query in the union separately and they both work fine. With both queries working independently of the union it would seem to indicate the issue is a union issue but as it worked previously with no change to the union it would seem to indicate a data issue so I am at a loss as what to do next to fix the issue.

```
select month([UD03].[Date02]) as 'Month',

datename(month,[UD03].[Date02]) as 'Month Name',

case
when ud03.key1=' ' then ud03.key2+ud03.key3+ud03.key4
when ud03.key2=' ' then ud03.key1+ud03.key3+ud03.key4
end,

Case 
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) < 10 then 'Under 10"'
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 10 and 19.999 then '10-19.999"'
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 20 and 29.999 then '20-29.999"'
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 30 and 39.999 then '30-39.999"'
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 40 and 49.999 then '40-49.999"'
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 50 and 59.999 then '50-59.999"'
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 60 and 69.999 then '60-69.999"'
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 70 and 79.999 then '70-79.999"'
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 80 and 89.999 then '80-89.999"'
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 90 and 99.999 then '90-99.999"'
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) >=100.000 then '100.000"+'
end as 'OD Range',
Case 
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) < 10 then 1
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 10 and 19.999 then 2
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 20 and 29.999 then 3
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 30 and 39.999 then 4
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 40 and 49.999 then 5
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 50 and 59.999 then 6
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 60 and 69.999 then 7
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 70 and 79.999 then 8
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 80 and 89.999 then 9
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) between 90 and 99.999 then 10
    when CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1) >0 and try_cast(SUBSTRING(ud03.shortchar02,1,CHARINDEX('x', ud03.ShortChar02,1)-1) as decimal(6,3)) >=100.000 then 11
end as 'Sort Order',
'Quotes' as 'Type',
Case 
        when [UD03].[CheckBox05]=0 and [UD03].[CheckBox06]=0 and [UD03].[CheckBox13]=0 then '63/63'
        when [UD03].[CheckBox06]=1 then '160/160'
    end as 'Mill'   
from Ice.UD03 as UD03
inner join Ice.UD02 as UD02 on 
UD03.Company = UD02.Company
And
CAST(CAST(UD03.Number09 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(30)) = UD02.Key1

left outer join Erp.Customer as Customer on 
UD03.Company = Customer.Company
And
UD03.Key1 = Customer.Name

left outer join Erp.SalesTer as SalesTer on 
Customer.Company = SalesTer.Company
And
Customer.TerritoryID = SalesTer.TerritoryID

left outer join Erp.CustGrup as CustGrup on 
Customer.Company = CustGrup.Company
And
Customer.GroupCode = CustGrup.GroupCode

 where (UD03.Key3 <> '0') and ([UD03].[Date02]>=CONVERT(datetime,'01/01/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(yy,@StartDate))) and [UD03].[Date02]<=CONVERT(datetime,'12/31/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(yy,@StartDate)))) and (([UD03].[CheckBox05]=0 and [UD03].[CheckBox06]=0 and [UD03].[CheckBox13]=0 and (ud03.key1 not like 'Crossett ASH%' and ud03.key1 not like 'Crossett TY%')) or [UD03].[CheckBox06]=1) and ([UD02].[ShortChar01]='Allo' or [UD02].[ShortChar01]='Carb' or [UD02].[ShortChar01]='S300' or [UD02].[ShortChar01]='S400') and (([UD03].[CheckBox05]=0 and [UD03].[CheckBox06]=0 and [UD03].[CheckBox13]=0) or ([UD03].[CheckBox06]=1)) and ud03.key1 not like 'Zurn%'

 union all

 select month([orderhed].OrderDate) as 'Month',

 datename(month,[orderhed].OrderDate) as 'Month Name',

cast(cast(orderhed.ordernum as nvarchar) + cast(orderdtl.orderline as nvarchar) as nvarchar) as 'Ordernumber and Line',
Case 
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3)) < 10 then 'Under 10"'
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3)) between 10 and 19.999 then '10-19.999"'
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 20 and 29.999 then '20-29.999"'
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 30 and 39.999 then '30-39.999"'
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 40 and 49.999 then '40-49.999"'
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 50 and 59.999 then '50-59.999"'
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 60 and 69.999 then '60-69.999"'
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 70 and 79.999 then '70-79.999"'
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 80 and 89.999 then '80-89.999"'
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 90 and 99.999 then '90-99.999"'
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))>=100.000 then '100.000"+'
end as 'OD Range',
Case 
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3)) < 10 then 1
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3)) between 10 and 19.999 then 2
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 20 and 29.999 then 3
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 30 and 39.999 then 4
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 40 and 49.999 then 5
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 50 and 59.999 then 6
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 60 and 69.999 then 7
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 70 and 79.999 then 8
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 80 and 89.999 then 9
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))between 90 and 99.999 then 10
    when try_cast(SUBSTRING(orderdtl.linedesc, CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)+2,
    (CHARINDEX('x',orderdtl.linedesc,1)-2)-CHARINDEX('- ', orderdtl.linedesc,1)) as decimal(6,3))>=100.000 then 11
end as 'Sort Order',
'Orders' as 'Type',
case 
    when [OrderDtl].[ProdCode] Like '63%' then '63/63'
    when [OrderDtl].[ProdCode] Like '160%' then '160/160'
end as 'Mill'
from Erp.OrderHed as OrderHed
inner join Erp.Customer as Customer on 
OrderHed.Company = Customer.Company
And
OrderHed.CustNum = Customer.CustNum

inner join Erp.OrderDtl as OrderDtl on 
OrderHed.Company = OrderDtl.Company
And
OrderHed.OrderNum = OrderDtl.OrderNum
left outer join Erp.SalesCat as SalesCat on 
SalesCat.Company = OrderDtl.Company
And
SalesCat.SalesCatID = OrderDtl.SalesCatID
where orderhed.OrderDate >=CONVERT(datetime,'01/01/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(yy,@StartDate))) and orderhed.OrderDate <=CONVERT(datetime,'12/31/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(yy,@StartDate))) and [OrderDtl].[ProdCode] <> 'KFRR' and [SalesCat].[Description] <> 'KFR630 Rings' and [SalesCat].[Description] <> 'Other' and orderhed.custnum <>942 and orderhed.custnum<>725 and customer.custnum <> 1086
```

Comment: There seems to be something missing from your question, can you guess what it is?

Comment: I can't imagine any possible way a UNION could cause the error you are getting.  We would need to see your queries to help.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if you don't post your query???

Comment: When you run them separately are you allowing it to return all of the data (Does your SQL client automatically limit the results it returns)? What if you stick an ORDER BY at the end of the individual queries. Does that cause the problem to come back (when run separately)?

Comment: Given the current info, the only thing I can say is if the query separately, it should work when you UNION it.

Comment: So I was using just union. Switched it to union all and everything seems to be working appropriately.

Comment: @Tom - If your problem is solved, so be it but changing from a `union` to a `union all` without changing anything else can't possibly have solved the issue.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I would agree with you but that seems to have fixed the issue. I will add the query itself to the question.

Comment: @Tom - tx. Just as verification: removing the `all` without changing anything else breaks it again?

Comment: It must be a difference in the execution plans between the UNION And UNION ALL. Where the UNION ALL is avoiding some oddball error that the UNION plan runs into. It seems unlikely, but it's possible. I think the `EXPLAIN` would be interesting here.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers yes, removing the all does break the query again.

Comment: @Tom - well, from the two of us, at least "I" learned something new ;)

Comment: I don’t see how `UNION` vs `UNION ALL` would be a problem, but I would like to caution you that your final `LEFT OUTER JOIN Erp.SalesCat` is being treated as an `INNER JOIN` due to your inclusion of that table in the `WHERE` clause.  You can remedy that by including those `WHERE` conditions in the `ON` clause, instead.

Comment: @Siyual thank you, that is good to know and I will look into how that is impacting the returned results.

Comment: @Tom - did you perhaps only retrieved the first x results? Can you navigate to the end of the resultset?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers so the first individual query returns 12421 rows that I can navigate to the end of and the second query returns 3196 rows that I am also able to navigate to the end of. With the union all i get 15617 returned results which seems to check out.

Comment: @Tom - thx for verifying but that leaves me puzzled. I have no idea why other than the suggestion made by JNevill.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I agree I'm at a loss as well. MJH in the first comment seemed to know immediately what the issue was based on his hint but im not sure how he came to that.

Comment: Perhaps you have a `ud03.ShortChar02` with an `x` at an unexpected index that ultimately gets removed from the resultset for both plans but gets evaluated when using a `union all` triggering the error. *MJH was referring to the missing SQL from your question I think.*